# Algebraic Topology advice

Tags: algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

I'm currently working through Allen Hatcher's Book on algebraic topology and I'm noticing his sluggishness in style, I was wondering what other book on algebraic topology would work well alongside hatcher's book that helps make the ideas a bit more concrete and isn't as unorganized. Thus far I'm looking at Rotman's text for algebraic topology which I hear is excellent. There's also Fulton's text. I'm right now leaning toward obtaining rotman's text since it looks really good for a first run through of algebraic topology.

Comment: Just a heads up, chapter 0 is 1000x more annoying than the other chapters.

Comment: I really enjoyed (and continue to enjoy) Rotman's book.  I think he does a great job separating the algebra and the topology, which helped my organize the ideas better in my head.  For instance, in Ch. 10 he proves results about transitive group actions in the abstract, and then applies these to the case of the fundamental group acting on a fiber.

Comment: I am not a fan of Hatcher, but then I learnt the theory before it appeared. I like Marvin Greenberg: Algebraic Topology, also Bredon: Topology and Geometry, Munkres Algebraic Topology. Finally the book by Dold:Lectures on Algebraic Topology is great, lots of good material there, not sure if its an introductory book though.

Comment: Rotman's book is rather long and he indicates many algebra and category than necessary . But anyway I usually find proof in his book and Hatcher's book along with Massey's book  .

Answer (score 3):

Try Tammo tom Dieck's [Algebraic Topology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3037190485). It is very detailed and a good supplement to Hatcher.

I'm learning the material myself, I follow Hatcher and for clarification and expansion of points I look up tom Dieck since it is so full of detail that it is easy to get lost in it.

Comment: Not to mention tom Dieck's book is [endorsed by Hatcher himself!](https://mathoverflow.net/a/8571/46717). :)

Comment: @Quasicoherent Hatcher's idea is fantastic. Some one should make a epub/pdf where clicking/tapping on sections expand into more detail or a site, this is just a few lines of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a really good lecture series by Dr. Jonathan Evans ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-c4pxa9lBY&list=PLN_4R2IuNuuTWD00k9BAB1fo0UldBHnME&ab_channel=JonathanEvans)). It covers the basic topics in undergraduate algebraic topology finishing with the perhaps the highlight discussing the Galois correspondence for covering spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think James R. Munkres's Elements of Algebraic Topology is a great advice. It marches towards the central topic of homology theory straight ahead without the redundant mention of homotopy theory of topological spaces. It is organized very well, with rigorous foundations and a lot of concise examples that provides geometric intuitions and help to think. The proofs are written so well, too, that the reader can very easily capture the essential ideas, like the proof of simplicial approximation theorem.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a considerable amount of time looking for the best algebraic topology for the graduate level. Among all of textbooks published by the end of 2022, I found Rotman's *[An Introduction to Algebraic Topology](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4576-6)* the best one.